# CSS - How do I select children of sibling elements?

Tags: html, css

If I have an HTML structure like:

```
<div id="name">
    <div class="wrapper"><input id="first-name" type="text" /></div>
    <div class="wrapper"><input id="last-name" type="text" /></div>
</div>
```

How do I target the `last-name` input field if the `first-name` input field has a certain class that is applied about user interaction?

For example, if a user clicks on the `first-name` input field, my JavaScript applies a "is-active" CSS class to it:

```
<div id="name">
    <div class="wrapper"><input id="first-name" class="is-active" type="text" /></div>
    <div class="wrapper"><input id="last-name" type="text" /></div>
</div>
```

I want to apply some CSS to the last-name field when that occurs.

I can't just do the following because the two `input` fields are not siblings.

```
input#first-name.is-active + input#last-name { }
```

I've tried something like this:

```
.wrapper input#first-name.is-active + .wrapper input#last-name { }
```

But that doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `</input>` is not allowed. You either need to self-close the `<input ... />` or simply omit the closing tag completely.

Comment: Several errors here, the /input ofcourse, but also the added text in the id field. Since you already use js, just add al class to the siblings with js?

Comment: Sorry, this is me just writing some simple HTML just to get the point across. I'm going to update my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible with current available CSS selectors as you've already noticed.

You can check if this `:focus-within` workaround would work for you ([browser support is very good](https://caniuse.com/css-focus-within), with IE being the usual exception):

```css
.wrapper:focus-within + .wrapper > #last-name {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="name">
    <div class="wrapper"><input id="first-name" type="text"></div>
    <div class="wrapper"><input id="last-name" type="text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a neat workaround! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a particular class using JS and apply some changes using css.

```js
if ( document.querySelector("#first-name").classList.contains("is-active") ) {
  document.querySelector("#last-name").classList.add("your-class");
} else {
  document.querySelector("#last-name").classList.remove("your-class");
}
```

```css
.your-class {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="name">
    <div class="wrapper"><input id="first-name" class="is-active" type="text"></input></div>
    <div class="wrapper"><input id="last-name" type="text"></input></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check out `classList.toggle`, saves you alot of typing.